# How to store image as a large object to Postgre SQL database using pg-large-object and pg-promise?

Tags: postgresql, express, pg-promise

From my React front app I send an image as a multipart-file to my Express backend. There I upload files using express-fileupload. The image file data in backend is in form:
`<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 ... >`

When trying to save the image data as large object to my PostgreSQL database, I try to use pg-large-object as advised in [Creating a new large object using a stream and pg-promise](https://github.com/Joris-van-der-Wel/node-pg-large-object).

However, I am unable to create the fileStream. If I give as input to CreateReadStream the Buffer as such, I get the error:

> "The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received <Buffer ff..."

If I convert the stream to Uint8Array, I get error:

> "The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received Uint8Array(38879) [255, 216, 255, ..."

I am unable to get Duplex and also Streamified to work. I do not want to create any extra files.

Is there an example somewhere that works? How to do it?

Comment: In my experience `bytea` is much better suited for storing "blobs"

Comment: So I also read from Postgre SQL documents, but I was ordered to use large object.